# PHP MYSQL query like not functional

Tags: php, mysql

i had table from my database :

**Table product**  :

```
id | name | type  | stock | code  | etc |
1  | pan  | ready | 0     | A23   | ome |
2  | ipad | pre   | 0     | B55   | tow |
3  | mouse| stock | 5     | C33   | ter |
```

---

**mysql query :**

```
$key = $_GET["key"];

$searchTermBits[] = " name LIKE '%".$key."%' or code LIKE '%".$key."%'  or etc LIKE '%".$key."%' and type != 'pre' and stock! ='0'  ";
```

---

**OUTPUT : when search keyword "tow"**

why the result still show record number 2?

2. ipad , pre , stock : 0 , code : B55 , etc : tow

even my query **type != 'pre' and stock! ='0'**

is that conflict with QUERY LIKE with **select type !='pre' or something** ?

but, if i changes the query like this.

```
$searchTermBits[] = "  code LIKE '%".$key."%'  and type != 'pre' and stock! ='0'  ";
```

the result is correct.

Comment: what are you trying to get with the query? I am trying to understand the question to help you build the query

Comment: i tried to get all field from table ,

Comment: $key in this case is "tow"

Comment: $key = $_GET["key"];

Comment: so something like this: "select * from tableName where name LIKE '%" .key . "%' and type != 'pre' and stock != '0'"; ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `AND` operator has higher precedence, meaning you query is identical to

```
(name like '%a%') or (name like '%b%') 
    or (name like '%c%' and type != 'pre' AND stock != 0)
```

So the additional conditions are only applied to the third `OR` case. For the query to behave how you want use the parenthesis:

```
" (name LIKE '%".$key."%' or code LIKE '%".$key."%'  or etc LIKE '%".$key."%')
    and type != 'pre' and stock! ='0'  "
```

Btw, if the `$key` is coming from an untrusted source (e.g. *any* kind of input from user) consider using prepared statement with placeholders instead.

Comment: It would be nice if you could explain what means **has higher precedence**, just for having the complete view of the situation.

Comment: bahaha, that's the problem, () OMG, i don't realize it, thanks brother

Answer (score 0):

Having into account the scarce information you provided, I thing Cthulhu has the correct answer. In addition if we consider the code you provided, I would advise you about [SQL injections](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inyecci%C3%B3n_SQL).

Answer (score 0):

Because the AND operator has higher precedence, so the last compare of your query is "FALSE OR TRUE" and the result is true. If you want to change the precedence you can use parentheses like this

```
" (name LIKE '%".$key."%' or code LIKE '%".$key."%'  or etc LIKE '%".$key."%') and type != 'pre' and stock !='0'  ";
```

this query returns false for the keyword "tow"